# Flutter pop sometimes fails

Tags: flutter

I cannot reproduce this issue, but sometimes at random places in the app, Navigator.pop fails with this error :

```
Bad state: No element
       at ListMixin.lastWhere(dart:collection)
       at NavigatorState.pop(navigator.dart:4994)
       at Navigator.pop(navigator.dart:2486)
```

From what I understand, it's looking for the page to pop in the history. I don't really know how I can be 6 screens deep into the app and have an empty history...

If anyone has had this kind of issue and found the root cause (again, this happens randomly through the app, I've seen it happen on drawers, bottomsheets and pages), that would be great to share.